# Interpretation of rescaled coefficients in OLS

Tags: r, least-squares

**Context**

To make the coefficients of regression coefficients comparable, one usually rescales by the standard deviation (see case 3 below). This means that the different regression coefficients can be compared in terms of their effect size (e.g. when the coefficient for `x1` is 2 and that of `x2` is 4, the effect of `x2` is twice as large as that of `x1`). This is not possible when `x2` and `x1` are otherwise measured on different scales, e.g. one having values ranging from 1 to 10 and the other from 1 to 20.

**Question**

But when I rescale the coefficient by two times the standard deviation (see case 2), I am not entirely sure how to interpret the coefficients. Does this mean that the unit of the new coefficient in case 2 is two times the standard deviation? This would mean that moving one unit in the explanatory variable `x_resc_two_times_sd` corresponds to a two times standard deviation, e.g. in case 2, this would be `5.6292`. Or do I have to multiply this effect by four because the standard deviation is 0.5?

```
## setting up artificial regression data
# number of points to sample
n_points <- 1000
# x-values
x <- runif(n_points, min = 0, max = 5)
# y-values with some random noise
y <- 2*x+6 + rnorm(n_points, mean = 6, sd = 2)
# quickly look at this
plot(x, y)

## Case 1: not rescaled
sd(x)
summary(lm(y ~ x))


## Case 2: rescaled by two times the sd
two_sd_func <- function(x){(x)/(2*sd(x, na.rm = T))} # function to rescale by 2*sd
x_resc_two_times_sd <- two_sd_func(x) 
sd(x_resc_two_times_sd)
summary(lm(y ~ x_resc_two_times_sd))



## Case 3: rescaled by one times the sd
one_sd_func <- function(x){(x)/(sd(x, na.rm = T))} # function to rescale by sd
x_resc_one_times_sd <- one_sd_func(x)
sd(x_resc_one_times_sd)
summary(lm(y ~ x_resc_one_times_sd))
```

**Output**

Case 1:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 12.14274    0.12856   94.45   <2e-16 ***
x            1.93071    0.04319   44.70   <2e-16 ***
```

Case 2:

```
Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          12.1427     0.1286   94.45   <2e-16 ***
x_resc_two_times_sd   5.6292     0.1259   44.70   <2e-16 ***
```

Case 3:

```
Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         12.14274    0.12856   94.45   <2e-16 ***
x_resc_one_times_sd  2.81461    0.06297   44.70   <2e-16 ***
```

Comment: The answer should be easy to see from the numbers you posted 2 * 2.81 = 5.63.

Comment: Yes, I know, it is quite an easy question. But I cannot make a mistake and am unsure. So, this means that if I would like to obtain the effect of a change in two standard deviations in case 2, I would have to multiply the effect by four as the standard deviation is 0.5?

Comment: You have $a \times b$ then you create $b' = b/c$ so for $a \times b = a' \times b'$ to hold what do you need to do with $a$ to get $a'$ ?

Comment: a' should be a/c. this means that rescaling by two times the sd provides a regression estimate representing the effect of a change in two sd in the explanatory variables. So in the example above, 5.6292 represents the effect of a two sd change in the explanatory variable on the dependent variable, right?